# Is this issue related with Laravel? i don't know much about it

Tags: php, laravel

[Today i went to my website and this what i found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP637.png)

And i'm really confused right now, is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: you need to give permission.it's the issue with the server permissions
/var/www/html/yourproject

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Comment: Next time maybe follow the [installation instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#installing-laravel)

Comment: do you have any scheduled tasks? or ran any artisan commands recently?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the below command on your server:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/projectpath
```

if you only want to give permission to storage folder then run below command:

```
chmod 775 /var/www/html/projectpath/storage
```

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not at all because of laravel.
It is occurring because there is no permission given to your storage folder to open the file.

So you need to give permission by using below command:

`sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/projectpath/storage`

777 command means you're giving all the permissions like read write open and making it accessible.